# ProgressDialog won't dismiss, on redirected url

Tags: java, android, progressdialog

i already created  simple webview with progress dialog, what's in my question is when url got redirected progress dialog wont dismiss. for example : i'm open url like : www.myweb.com/account. then it redirect to : www.myweb.com/login. any solution to handle this?

```
//progress dialog
    ProgressDialog loading;

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        loading= new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this, R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle);
        loading.setMessage("Sedang Memuat...");
        loading.setCancelable(false);
        loading.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            if (loading.isShowing()) {
                loading.dismiss();
            }
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205056/android-webview-loading-dialog-not-being-dismissed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Webview loading dialog not being dismissed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205056/android-webview-loading-dialog-not-being-dismissed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that `onPageFinished` is getting called on each redirect, it maybe due to the use of `Iframe` or something else. I think you should override `onProgressChanged` in `WebChromeClient` like this:

```
myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){

        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
            super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);

           if(newProgress <100){
            prDialog.setMessage("Please wait ...");
            prDialog.show();
        }

          else if (newProgress ==100){
               if(prDialog!=null && prDialog.isShowing()){
                  prDialog.dismiss();
        }
       }
    }
```

Comment: What does the log say? Are you initializing `ProgressDialog`?

Comment: You should initialize `ProgressDialog` in `onCreate` if you are using `Activity` or in `onCreateView` if you are using fragments.

Comment: already tried your suggestion, and its solve my problem thanks bro :)
seems like, `setWebChromeClient()` can handle redirection very well (y).

Answer (score 0):

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClientClass());
 String url = "http://google.com/";
 webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
       webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
        webView.loadUrl(url);



private class WebViewClientClass extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            prDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewsActivity.this);
            prDialog.setMessage("Please wait ...");
            prDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            if(prDialog!=null){
                prDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
loading.setCancelable(false);
```

Set this to true as :

```
loading.setCancelable(true);
```

Also instead of this:

```
if (loading.isShowing()) {
                loading.dismiss();
            }
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
```

Use this:

```
super.onPageFinished(view, url);
if (loading!=null) {
            loading.dismiss();
        }
```

Also try commenting this line :

```
super.onPageFinished(view, url);
```

Another way is if its not dismissing somehow you can hide this in that case you have to do this:

After:

```
loading.show();
```

Add this:

```
loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

and after this:

```
loading.dismiss();
```

add this:

```
loading.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Comment: If this works for you dont forget to mark this post as answer. Happy Coding :)

Comment: its only mean we can dismiss it when we click it, but if we dont the loading wont dismiss :(

Comment: Buddy I added one more thing try this too. Hope it helps

Comment: setVisibility attribute can't applied bcs it's progressDialog not progressBar